# Preventing `willMoveToParentViewController` from being called when the view controller is added

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

In my application, when the user presses the back button on the navigation bar, I want the program to trigger some action. Therefore, I had been using `willMoveToParentViewController`. However, the method gets called when the viewController is added or removed. What is the way to prevent it from being called when the viewController is added? If there was an alternate way to detect when the backButton in the navigationBar was pressed, please suggest it.

Thanks!

Comment: How about `viewDidDisappear`? Check the documentation here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidDisappear:

Comment: thanks for suggestion.. let me just give it a shot.

Comment: works.. thanks for the suggestion.. i was too stuck with the above mentioned method and couldn't think out of the box for a while :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `viewDidDisappear` for the same. You can check the apple [documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidDisappear). This notifies the view controller when its view is removed from a view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can just check if parent is `nil` in `willMoveToParentViewController`.  It will be `nil` when the back button is pressed.

For example:

```
override func willMoveToParentViewController(parent: UIViewController?) {
    super.willMoveToParentViewController(parent)
    if parent == nil {
        // view controller being removed (back button)
        // could use this area for passing back some variables 
        //   or whatever else you needed to do when back is hit
    } else {
        // view controller being added, do nothing
    }
}
```